# Quote Tcl argument

Tags: escaping, tcl, quotes

I have a quotation problem in Tcl. I have a long list of signals from which in a for loop I assign each single one to `my_sig` and then parse it.

```
foreach sig $list_of_sigs {
    set my_sig $sig
}
```

One example of what I get back is:

```
set my_sig top.sub.sig[0]
```

How do I use `my_sig` in commands to follow such that "`[`" and "`]`" are automatically escaped? For example, my commands accept:

```
my_command -filter signal_bit=="top.sub.sig\[0\]"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is my_command a tcl command?  Or an executable?

Comment: It is a built in Tcl command.

Comment: This looks like a Synopsys tool. Synopsys's interpreter automatically expands [x] to "[x]" allowing you to type bus names without quotation. So I'm a little surprised you are needing to quote the signal name at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't normally have to do that, as Tcl doesn't reinterpret the contents of variables unless explicitly asked to. Something is expanding the value again and you probably ought to chase that down as it's actually insecure in a formal sense, and that tends to correlate with the code being slow too.

That said, it's pretty easy to add quoting with `string map`. All it takes is a little care with the quoting of the backslashes.

```
foreach sig $list_of_sigs {
    set my_sig [string map {[ {\[} ] {\]}} $sig]
    # ... etc ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
set my_sig {top.sub.sig[0]}
my_command -filter signal_bit==$my_sig
```

Comment: That doesn't help, unfortunately. Maybe I should refine my problem.
top.sub.sig[0] is something I get from another command which I run in a for loop.
In other words `my_sig` takes only one value from the long list of signals.

Comment: It is very specific to the tool I am using... I just want to get some checks from the tool which are created for each single signal or bit.

Comment: If it is a signal, no problem. Bits are giving me the hard time here.

Comment: I have a feeling this is an XY problem. You haven't actually told us what your errors are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to escape the special characters.

```
regsub -all {([\[\]])} $sig "\\\\\\1" sig
```

References: [regsub](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.htm)  [re_syntax](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: Actually, `regsub -all {\[} $sig {\[}` will suffice since a closing bracket is only special if there is an unescaped opening bracket. (To the uninitiated: this looks like “replace A with A”, but because of how `regsub` interprets its arguments, it’s actually “replace A’ with A”, where A’ is A after substitution.)